# In Git, how can I get the hash for a given file at a specified tag?

Tags: git

I want to get the hash for a file at multiple different tags.

I thought that

```
git show --pretty=format:%h  V2-0-1:./MyFile.txt
```

would do it, but that just spits out the whole file contents.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the hash for a file"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rev-parse` is the all-purpose tool for turning any object specifier into its hash ID:

```
git rev-parse V2-0-1:./MyFile.txt
```

will find the blob hash for that file.  (You only need the `./` if you are in a subdirectory.)

Note that you can also get a commit or its tree:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c
$ git rev-parse HEAD:
691408489fb0028188472ddca75fc930c58c5f11
$ git rev-parse HEAD:Makefile
e4b503d259906d60a65204248aeb54962b12c062
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can this also do multiple files at a time?

Comment: Yes: try `git rev-parse HEAD:path1 HEAD:path2`. Consider how to handle the failure result when at least one such path does not exist in the selected commit, though. (Experiment with the output of `git rev-parse`, taking note of which strings go to stdout and which go to stderr.)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
git ls-tree V2-0-1 .\MyFile.txt
```

Although you then have to do a bit of parsing to get just the hash.

Is there an even easier way?
(Also, why does the documentation main screen not show ls-tree?)